# Prevent assigning to rvalue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variable-assignment

Say I have a class with an overridden assignment operator:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test& operator =(const Test&) {return *this;}
};

Test f();
```

Is there any way to make it a compile-time error to assign to the result of a function?

Examples:

```
f() = test();

Test t;
f() = t;

// if there were also a Test Test::operator+(Test);
(t + t) = test();
```

This already happens for primitive types, and I want to replicate it for this class:

```
int g();
g() = 5; // error
(3 + 4) = 5; // error
```

Edit: I'm using Visual C++, which doesn't support all of C++11. Specifically, it doesn't support ref-qualifiers.

Comment: Make f() return `const Test`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want your `operator=()` to be invoked on temporaries (rvalues), then qualify it *lvalue* as:

```
Test& operator =(const Test&) & {return *this;}
                           //^^^ note this
```

Now the following

```
f() = t;
```

will give compilation error.

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes. It has been more than 2 years since C++11 is released. So I would assume C++11 is the default now, unless specifically specified.

Comment: This is a good answer for the question I asked, but I forgot to mention I'm using Visual C++ which doesn't support these.

Comment: @immibis: Ohh.. in that case, you don't have any ideal solution now. Anyway, I will keep this answer for educational purpose as it might help others!

Comment: @Nawaz That's not very realistic.  It usually takes at least 5 years for a new version of the standard to be widely and reliably implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you can ref-qualify your assignment operator so that it can only be called on lvalue references. However, I can't find anything definite in the standard about whether such an operator is still *the* copy assignment operator.

In C++03, people came up with the idea of only returning const objects from functions, but that's a bad idea because it prevents moving in C++11.

In the end, it's probably not worth going to any effort to do this.